# Set source port when sending udp message with echo?

Tags: bash, udp, port, netcat

I'm using

```
echo "This is my data" > /dev/udp/192.168.0.92/7891
```

in a bash script to test udp communication with a device. The device then returns the message. I've seen via wireshark that my source port is always changing.

Anyway, I want to set the source port, can I do that?

Comment: every time I call the script the source port of my message changes. for example, the first time its 1234 and next its 332211. olivs answer works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use netcat `nc` and its `-p` option to set the source port.

As said in the netcat man page

> -p source_port
> Specify the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.

Then use it like this:

```
echo "This is my data"  | nc -u -p 50000 192.168.0.92 7291
```